# Convert Python dictionary to a JSON array

Tags: python, arrays, json, api, dictionary

Here's my function which connects to an API:

```
def order_summary():
    """Get order summary for a specific order"""
    # Oauth2 params
    headerKey = api_login()
    headers = {'Authorization': headerKey}

    # Payload params
    payloadOrderSum = {
        "domainId": 15,
        "domainName": "SGL",
        "orderId": 3018361
    }

    # API response
    orderSumResp = requests.post(url + "order/summary", data=payloadOrderSum, headers=headers)
    print(orderSumResp.content)
```

The API expects a JSON array as Payload Params which essentially looks like that:

```
[
  {
    "domainId": 0,
    "domainName": "string",
    "orderId": 0
  }
]
```

The other endpoints I coded for on this API didn't need for the params to be an array so I could just use them as is and send them as a dictionary and it worked.

I've tried a couple things using the JSON library but I can't seem to get it to work. I saw that the JSonEncoder converts lists and tuples to JSON arrays but I couldn't figure it out.

Not sure what other info I could provide but just ask if there are any.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap `payloadOrderSum` into a list:

```
payloadOrderSum = {
    "domainId": 15,
    "domainName": "SGL",
    "orderId": 3018361
}

orderSumResp = requests.post(url + "order/summary", json=[payloadOrderSum], headers=headers)
```

Note that I used `json` kwarg instead of `data` ([added in version 2.4.2](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.post)).

Comment: By far the easiest to solve it. Thanks! Don't even need the JSON library anymore. That REQUESTS library kicks ass!

Comment: @Alex glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

dump your dict with json.dumps [requests-doc](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)

```
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload))
```

Answer (score 0):

It could help if you specify what you tried with the JSON library.

However, you might wanna try this if you haven't already done so:

```
import json
payloadOrderSum = json.dumps(
    {
    "domainId": 15,
    "domainName": "SGL",
    "orderId": 3018361
    }
)
```